# $n$ students are standing in a circle. Find the number of ways in which $k$ students can be selected such that no two of them are together.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The question is

$n$ students are standing in a circle.  Find the number of ways in which $k$ students can be selected such that no two of them are together.

I know one method to do this by comparing it with a question like "find number of triangles that can be formed inside an $n$-sided polygon such that no side of triangle is common to the $n$-sided polygon" but that'll be valid only when $k=3$.

I want to know general method to solve such questions and also the principle behind that method.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No. of polygons in a polygon with no side coinciding.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3051303/no-of-polygons-in-a-polygon-with-no-side-coinciding)

Comment: It will be easier to understand with a specific value for $k$. Check out  [Counting heptagons formed using vertices of n-sided polygon having no sides in common with the polygon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663877/counting-heptagons-formed-using-vertices-of-n-sided-polygon-having-no-sides-in?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @zaira Thanks for sharing those but I am having a tough time understanding them. I'd like if someone writes a more elaborated answer on this.Doesn't matter if he/she solves it for a particular values of n and k

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yes that's helpful too!Thanks for sharing.Though I am having problem in understanding the "solution to the recurrence part(the **obvious** part :/ )" . His final result is giving me the correct answer that I require ,so his question answers what I want. I'll try to understand again after sometime maybe I'll get it then..Also,Thank you for the Edit.

Comment: @Ashutosh Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which I forgot to tell you about earlier, explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: There is another approach to the same problem in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362574/selecting-objects-arranged-in-a-circle-solution-only-by-counting?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @N.F.Taussig by the way ,are u familiar with method for selection in which we take approach as :- Taking varibales $x,y,z,w etc$ and then putting $x+y+z+w=n$ and, since all these are integers ,we write their maximum and minimum values. And then proceed for answer by "Coefficient of $\alpha^k$ in ($\alpha^2 + \alpha^3$ +... ).. If you are familiar with this approach ,can u help me solving this problem using this as this is the method I'll be able to grasp easily

Comment: I didn't get my required answer and you guys closed my question 

Comment: You may find Brian M. Scott's addendum to his answer in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1953628/20-people-are-sitting-around-a-circular-table-how-many-ways-can-we-choose/1953711#1953711) useful.

Comment: Yassss ,finally that helps!!!!!!